# Whats is wrong with this extendible hashing solution?

Tags: database, hash, indexing, hashtable

I'm trying to grasp the concept of extendible hashing, but I'm getting confused about the distribution of values to the buckets.

For example:

Say I want to insert 6 values from scratch: 17, 32, 14, 50, 35, 21

What would be wrong with this as a solution:

Global depth = 2
Bucket size = 2

```
00[] --> [][]
01[] --> [][]
10[] --> [][]
11[] --> [][]
```

Does this mean only one value for each hash value will be pointed to the bucket, so then you increment the global depth? Or would this work?

I understand the beginning of the process, I am just confused at this point.

Comment: Bucket is not an array, think of it as a linked list.

Comment: '[][]' was just a graphical notation of a bucket with a size of 2.  I didn't mean it was an array

Comment: Than i don't understand your question, sorry. 
The idea of the hash is to put this values into buckets. Ok, you've selected 2 bits as a "hash" for a value. 14 and 50 will go to the same bucket, 17 and 21 also. 
What is your question?

Comment: So the solution is Ok? I just got confused about what values are being put into the buckets, for example I though that 01[] would only put one unique value in the bucket not multiple values.

Comment: Yes, it's good. Imagine now you want to check if 21 is in the list. You get last two bits = 01 and find a bucket immediately. Next you need to search in a bucket. Searching among two elements is faster than searching between six. That's your profit.

Of course if you expect, for example 1000 elements you should increase global depth. But not on the fly.

Comment: Also consider choosing some good hash function depending on what are you gonna hash. For strings maybe sum modulo 256 will be good for ex.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong in the solution that you've provided just that the global depth need not be increased. The solution is perfectly compatible with the given global depth.

Assuming that we choose the directory and the corresponding bucket using the 2 left most bits. Then, the solution would look like the following
Also the numbers in the binary format would look like the following

17 - **01**0001
32 - **10**0000
14 - **00**1110
50 - **11**0010
35 - **10**0011
21 - **01**0101

directory   -------------   buckets
00-----------------------> 14 |
01-----------------------> 17 | 21
10-----------------------> 32 | 35
11-----------------------> 50 |

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't increment global depth.
The whole idea of the hash is to select such function that it would put items in a buckets more or less equally.

That depends on a hash function.
You can use something as complex as md5 as a hash and than you will get 1 element in 1 bucket but you're not really *guaranteed* that there will be only 1.

So a general implementation should use binary search on buckets and some other search inside bucket. You can't and you shouldn't change hash function on the fly.